# Remove hover color for image link

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using this code to display an image link in the `show` view:

```
<%= link_to( image_tag("wikipedia.org.png", {alt: "Wikipedia", size: "24x24"}), @entity.wikipedia_url, {class: "plain", :target => "_blank", :rel=>"nofollow"} ) if @entity.wikipedia_url.present?  %>
```

Which results in this when the mouse is over the image link:

[image]

The HTML that is generated:

```
<a class="plain" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/foobar" rel="nofollow" target="_blank"><img alt="Wikipedia" src="/assets/wikipedia.org.png" height="24" width="24"></a>
```

I would like to remove the hover color for image links, while retaining it for text links.

As such, I added:

```
a.plain {
  &:hover {
        text-decoration: none;
  }
}
```

to the original `scaffold.css.scss`:

```
a {
  color: #000;
  &:visited {
    color: #666;
  }
  &:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #000;
  }
}
```

This did not remove the hover color.  What do I need to change?

Comment: Use `a{color: #000;} a:visited{color: #666;} a:hover{color:#fff; background: #000} `

Comment: @TylerH: that didn't work for me (I removed the `.plain` code), but the `background` attribute certainly helped.  Thanks.

Comment: Oh, sorry! I scrolled down so far that I couldn't see your first code box with `.plain` in it.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it in CSS:

```
a {color: #000;} 
a:visited {color: #666;} 
// `!important` overwrites whatever you or who else set before for the a element.
a:hover {color: #fff!important; background-color: #000;}
```

Comment: The only reason I could think of is  that sometimes when you call an object by the specific id class position or type, this element gets the new style. This always depends if there is something more specif at the moment of applying the style. Lets say i have

Comment: <p>p{color:#fff;}/*white*/</p>
<p>p.n{color:#00f;}/*blue*/</p>
<p>.n{color:#f00;}/*red*/</p>
as p.n is more specific a the moment you go over the p element the color of this element for sure will be blue, now if you hover the other element without the class, this one it will be white.

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```
a.plain {
  &:hover {
    background: none;
  }
}
```